# How can manage multiple theme in application?

Tags: php, css, themes

I am trying to develop multiple theme concept in my application. But exactly how can achieve it, i don't know?

I have done so far that created multiple CSS(style-sheet) and given option to user to select any one desirable theme among them. Where i am going to include my css, just checking that which theme selected by user. Example like below

```html
if($user_theme_selected == 'basic')
{
      echo '<link href="/plugins/bootstrap/css/theme-basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>';
}
else if($user_theme_selected == 'premium')
{
      echo '<link href="/plugins/bootstrap/css/theme-premium.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>';
}
else
{
      echo '<link href="/plugins/bootstrap/css/theme-default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>';
}
```

am i going in right way to apply multiple theme in my application?

Or anyone have better and simpler way to do it?

Comment: If by 'theme' you mean another CSS, then it seems to me that this is the way to go. Your code could be better optimized, but the basic idea is sound: Load the CSS file that belongs to a theme.

Comment: If i want to change some look and feel then what is the procedure?

Comment: Saying 'some look and feel' is way too vague. Do you mean something other than CSS styles? If so, then what exactly? Give an example.

Comment: Ok. I want to say that in some of theme header height is small and in other medium. Or may be to change some section position like remove login form from left panel and keep it to right panel as per selected theme. Hope you are get my points.

Comment: Well, both could be done with styles, but suppose you want to change the HTML? In that case you could work with 'templates' that depend on the theme. Look in google for: 'php template engine', and you will find a lot of them: Dwoo, Twig, Smarty, Savant. To compare them see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines For small changes you could write your own code.